# Is it possible to save few list, each one is in another column in CSV file? JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Is it possible to save lists in another columns in csv?
All of this list have another size. I have this code but it works only for first column.

```
public static <T> void saveToCsv(String fileName, List<T> elements){
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\win\\Desktop\\test\\"+fileName+".csv");
    if(file.exists())
        fileName = fileName+ UUID.randomUUID();
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\win\\Desktop\\test\\"+fileName+".csv"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (T csv : elements)
        pw.println(csv);

    pw.close();
}
```

For example i have 4 lists and I want output like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnGow.png)

I thought about function which concatenates items with the same index, but my lists have diffrent sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge a list of lists using the following method:

```
public static <T> List<String> mergeLists(List<List<T>> lists){
    Collections.sort(lists, (x, y) -> y.size() - x.size());
    List<String> result = lists.remove(0).stream().map(e -> e.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    int longestListSize = result.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < longestListSize; i++) {
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder(result.get(i).toString());
        for(List<T> list : lists) {
            if(i < list.size()) {
                row.append(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        result.set(i, row.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

If it's necessary for you to use a list of generic type then modify columns merging but String should be enough for a csv file.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed!